# I need to find all the peaks and valleys in a list of data points using c#

Tags: c#

This is my entire program. I have been working on this project for a week now and I am simply stuck.  I have managed to read the CSV file and put the information in two lists that I then converted into arrays.  Now I don't HAVE to do it like this. It's just simply what I managed to write and work and make sense in my head.  This is where I've managed to get to and where I'm stuck.  All I need is to be able to parse out ALL the peaks, or maximums, and valleys, or minimums, from the data points, and display them.  If I can get that to happen then I can finally be done with this program.  Any help and suggestions, code, anything like that would greatly appreciate.  Like I said if you have a better formula that I can plug in and use without hard-coding points (because there's over 2000 of them) and display the outcome in a `listbox` or something then that would make my day. Thank y, everyone,ne in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double firstX, firstY, secondX, secondY, thirdX, thirdY, rw, cl = 0.0;

        int count = 0;

        string x = "";
        string y = "";

        byte MinMax = 0; //0 equals rising, 1 equals falling

        double Max = new Array[];
        //double Min = new Array[];

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\data.csv"))
            {
                List<string> listA = new List<string>();
                List<string> listB = new List<string>();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    listA.Add(values[0]);
                    listB.Add(values[1]);

                    string[] xPoints = listA.ToArray();
                    string[] yPoints = listB.ToArray();

                    while (yPoints.Last() != null)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToDouble(yPoints.First()) == 0.0)
                        {
                            firstY = Convert.ToDouble(yPoints.First());
                        }

                        if (Convert.ToDouble(yPoints.First()) != 0.0 && secondY == 0.0)
                        {
                            secondY = Convert.ToDouble(yPoints.Last());

                            if (secondY > firstY)
                            {
                                MinMax = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MinMax = 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (secondY != 0.0 && thirdY == 0.0)
                        {
                            thirdY = Convert.ToDouble(yPoints.Last());

                            if (MinMax == 0 && thirdY > secondY)
                            {
                                firstY = secondY;
                                secondY = thirdY;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Max[count,0] = secondY;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    listBox1.Items.Add(values[0]);
                    listBox2.Items.Add(values[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the apex point between three consecutive values? E.g. [2,9,4], peak = 9 (index 3) ? Do you need the index of the peak/valley or the raw value of it?

Comment: I need every maximum (peak) and every minimum (valley) throughout the set of points. so I don't need it just to do one, I need it to do them all and store the peaks in one list/array and displayed, and the peaks in another list/array and display them. the rest of the points aren't needed

Comment: Are listA and listB both contains points (peak and valley)? Can show some sample data and result you want? edit your question with the sample and what data is in side csv file?

Comment: ListA and listB contain the x coordinate points and the y coordinate points.  listA has the x coords, listB has the y coords.  That's another thing, the peaks and valleys show up in the y coord, not the x coord

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will get valleys and peaks on an array of y values, ignoring [0]

```
public void GetValleysAndPeaks(double[] yValues, out List<int> peakIndexes, out List<int> valleyIndexes)
{
    peakIndexes = new List<int>();
    valleyIndexes = new List<int>();

    bool directionUp = yValues[0] <= yValues[1];
    for(int i = 1; i < yValues.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(directionUp && yValues[i + 1] < yValues[i])
        {
            peakIndexes.Add(i);
            directionUp = false;
        }
        else if(!directionUp && yValues[i + 1] > yValues[i])
        {
            valleyIndexes.Add(i);
            directionUp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the snippet.  Now I'm working on getting the information into the formula from what I already have

Comment: You may need to end the loop on `i < yValues.Length-1`

Comment: @HansKesting True

Comment: I'm not following the `directionUp` approach. Why is this boolean value a constant for every loop of the iteration? Isn't a peak defined by having `yValues[peak + 1] < yValues[peak] && yValues[peak - 1] < yValues[peak]`? (analogously using `>` for valleys). Your current example would be unable to have both a peak and a valley in a single graph, which seems like a major oversight.

Comment: @Flater I somehow missed that. Fixed it now.

Comment: So I get how this formula works, and I appreciate it 100%.  For w/e reason though I can't figure out how to plug my information into it.  I know it's probably trivial; but I'm just drawing and absolute blank on how to incorporate the snippet of code into my overall program